# C++ designing a container with expiration/duration

Tags: c++, pthreads, containers, deadlock

I need to provide a small associative array (say TimedMap), where key and value type is not decided. This associative array, has a fixed duration for all of its elements. For example, suppose the key type is 'int', and the value type is 'Foo', and the duration is 5 seconds. If I insert (0, Foo instance), then after 5 seconds, the value should be gone.

Since my co-worker who will use this associative array, does not want to lock/unlock for get/set operation of the array, and suppose that I have no other choice.  And except boost::shared_ptr, I am not allowed to use boost for some reason.

The TimedMap instances should be used only few places, so I decided to create a thread for each instance, then check regularly all elements so that it can remove the key, value pair if it is expired.

This is how the user of TimedMap will use:

```
typedef TimedMap<int, boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > TMAP;
TMAP m(5);      // each key, value pair will have 5 seconds lifetime.

m.set(0, boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()));

{ 
  TMAP::Ptr ptr = m.get(0);  // index 0, and value is locked at this time
  if (ptr) { // if it was in the map,
    // use (*ptr).xxx() to access Foo::xxx.
  }
} // now, 'ptr' is gone, so the lock will be gone.
```

Right now, except the thread thing, I think I implemented the rest.
There are two types of lock, one lock per each TimedMap instance, and there will be a lock per element, to be used to guard each element.

The problem is, sometimes, when the TimedMap instance destructor called, the main lock was in locked state for unknown reason.  I checked for a while, and found nothing.

I know that placing a lock in the element of the standard container, but I can't think of better solution for now.

Could you help me with this?  To compile it,

```
$ g++ timedmap.cpp
```

My appology, I couldn't abridge the source shorter.

timedmap.h:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <string>

#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define M_LOCK(m)       ((m).lock())
#define M_UNLOCK(m)     ((m).unlock())
#define M_TRYLOCK(m)    ((m).trylock())

template <typename K, typename V>
class TimedMap {
  class MUTEX {
    ::pthread_mutex_t lck_;

  public:
    MUTEX(const MUTEX &m) {
      // copy CTOR
      int type = PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT;
      ::pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
      ::pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
      ::pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, type);
      ::pthread_mutex_init(&lck_, &attr);
      ::pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
    }

    MUTEX(int type = PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT) {
      ::pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
      ::pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
      ::pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, type);
      ::pthread_mutex_init(&lck_, &attr);
      ::pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
    }

    ~MUTEX() {
      int ret = ::pthread_mutex_destroy(&lck_);
      if (ret) {
        // pthread_mutex_destroy() failed
        if (ret == EBUSY) {
          // locked?
        }
        //abort();
      }
    }

    int lock() {
      int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&lck_);
      if (ret) {                // lock failed
        abort();
      }
      return ret;
    }

    int unlock() {
      int ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&lck_);
      if (ret) {                // unlock failed
        abort();
      }
      return ret;
    }

    bool trylock() {
      int ret = pthread_mutex_trylock(&lck_);
      if (ret != 0 && ret != EBUSY) { // trylock failed
        abort();
      }
      return ret ? false : true;
    }
  };

  struct TMENT {
    time_t tm_;
    MUTEX m_;
    V val_;

    TMENT() : tm_(time(0)), m_(), val_() {}
    TMENT(const V &val) : tm_(time(0)), m_(), val_(val) {
    }
    void refresh() { tm_ = time(0); }
    bool expired(time_t expiration) {
      time_t now = ::time(0);
      return (now - tm_) > expiration;
    }
  };

  typedef std::map<K, TMENT> map_type;

  typedef typename map_type::key_type key_type;
  typedef typename map_type::mapped_type mapped_type;
  typedef typename map_type::value_type value_type;

  TimedMap(const TimedMap &);
  map_type map_;
  MUTEX mlock_;
  int expiration_;
  bool refresh_;

public:
  explicit TimedMap(int expiration)
    : map_(), mlock_(PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK),
      expiration_(expiration), refresh_(false) {
  }

  ~TimedMap() {
    clear();
  }

  void clear() {
    M_LOCK(mlock_);
    typename map_type::iterator i = map_.begin();
    while (i != map_.end()) {
      TMENT &ent = (*i).second;
      M_LOCK(ent.m_);
      M_UNLOCK(ent.m_);
      map_.erase(i++);
    }
    M_UNLOCK(mlock_);
  }

  class Ptr {
    TMENT *ent_;

    mutable bool owned_;

    bool yield() const {
      if (!owned_) {
        // Ptr can't yield ownership when it doesn't");
        abort();
      }
      owned_ = false;
      return true;
    }

    Ptr &operator=(const Ptr &ptr);

  public:
    Ptr(const Ptr &ptr) : ent_(ptr.ent_) {
      owned_ = ptr.yield();
    }
    Ptr() : ent_(0), owned_(false) {}

    Ptr(TMENT *ent) : ent_(ent), owned_(true) {}

    ~Ptr() {
      if (owned_)
        M_UNLOCK(ent_->m_);
    }

    V *operator->() {
      if (!owned_)
        throw std::out_of_range("not found");
      return &(ent_->val_);
    }

    V &operator*() {
      if (!owned_)
        throw std::out_of_range("not found");
      return ent_->val_;
    }

    operator bool() {
      if (owned_)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
  };

  void set(const key_type &k, const V &v) {
    M_LOCK(mlock_);
    typename map_type::iterator i = map_.find(k);
    if (i == map_.end()) {
      map_[k] = TMENT(v);
    }
    else {
      TMENT &ent = (*i).second;
      M_LOCK(ent.m_);
      ent.refresh();
      ent.val_ = v;
      M_UNLOCK(ent.m_);
    }
    M_UNLOCK(mlock_);
  }

  Ptr get(const key_type &k) {
    M_LOCK(mlock_);

    typename map_type::iterator i = map_.find(k);

    if (i == map_.end()) {
      // key not found
      M_UNLOCK(mlock_);
      return Ptr();
    }

    TMENT &ent = (*i).second;

    M_LOCK(ent.m_);

    if (ent.expired(expiration_)) {
      // key expired
      M_UNLOCK(ent.m_);
      return Ptr();
    }
    else if (refresh_)
      ent.refresh();

    M_UNLOCK(mlock_);

    // Intentionally leave the 'ent' as locked state.
    return Ptr(&ent);
  }
};
```

timedmap.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <time.h>

#include "timedmap.h"

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
  }
  ~Foo() {
  }

  const char *what() {
    return "foo";
  }

};

typedef TimedMap<int, boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > TMAP;

int
main(void)
{
  {
    TMAP m(5);

    int key = 0;
    {
      m.set(key, boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()));
    }

    bool loop = true;

    {
      while (loop) {
        {
          TMAP::Ptr ptr = m.get(key);

          if (ptr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "main: key(%d) = %s\n", key, (*ptr)->what());
          }
          else {
            fprintf(stderr, "main: key(%d) was not there\n", key);
            break;
          }
        }
        //break;
        usleep(100000);
        //sleep(1);
      }
    }
    m.clear();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a 3rd field which is the *life-time* of the element.

You would need to have a `friend` method that wakes up every resolution time and decrements the life-time.  When the life-time reaches zero, the element is removed.

You will need a separate thread of execution for processing the life-time because you don't want to suspend (block) the client's thread.

The implementation is OS specific, or involves OS specific features.

Also, use mutexes or another mechanism to prevent the Client's thread from accessing the elements while the life-time process is active.

**Edit 1:**
Since the container can be modified by the *life-time* task, the contain should be marked as `volatile`.

Comment: Actually, my problem is, even if it looks fine, but running above sample causes deadlock. And I don't know why. :(